# Retrieving MSSQL Data In Cordova App Using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, sql-server, ajax, cordova

I had created some simple mobile app in Cordova before but do not have any idea to create database app.

Here database app means create app using MSSQL Server, HTML and PHP and for that I had visited many sites for search of proper Article regarding the same but not find any  hence I here by present with some conclusion as below.

This is php file created by text file and save it with .php extension.

```
<?php
$mysql_db_hostname="MYSERVER NAME";
$mysql_db_user="Mee The User";
$mysql_db_password="My Password";
$mysql_db_database="database Name";

$con = @mysqli_connect($mysql_db_hostname,$mysql_db_user,$mysql_db_password,$mysql_db_database);

if(!$con)
{
  trigger_error('Could Not Connect To MySql:' . mysqli_connect_error());    
}

$var=array();
$sql="select * from rec";

$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($obj=mysqli_fetch_object($result))
{
  $var[]=$obj;
}

echo '{"rec":'.json_encode($var).'}';
?>
```

This is HTML File

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<table class="mGrid" id="jsondata">
<thead>
<th>ID</th>
<th>NAME</th>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready (function(){
var url="getjson.php";
$(#jsondata tbody).html("");
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
$.each(data.rec, function(i,recc){
var newRow=
"<tr>"
+"<td>"+recc.id+"</td>"
+"<td>"+recc.name+"</td>"
+"</tr>";
$(newRow).appendTo("#jsondata tbody");
});
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It is just shows the table head  but doesn’t shows any data or any sql connection error.

I want to know is it the wright way to create PHP Page from Text File and save it on .php extension for utilize it in cordova for retrieving data from SQL SERVER?.

I am not familiar of MYSQL as I just use MS SQL SERVER hence it is good if I am able to develop mobile application by using MSSQL Server,PHP and HTML.

Suggest me proper way.

Comment: set error report and do not suppress error by @mysqli  in your query, then tell us what is the error.

Comment: @MarkNg I had already trigger error on php file but do not throw any error instead it just shows table head only without data

Comment: edit ur post to tag javascript, is ur php file name correct?

Answer (score 0):

Use php and mssql or mysql at the backend of the mobile application ie. on the server side.create api's to link the server and the mobile application.
The mobile application communicate to the server with the help of these api's.You can request and get response via the api's.In most of the scenarios the mobile application request to the server with an AJAX call,do the required functions in the server and respond to the client [mobile application] in a json format,the mobile application can then further do its process with this returned data.
You cannot use any server-side scripting language like php inside cordova. But using Jquery and AJAX you can call php functions and get data easily.